# GUI fails, out of space on system drive

Tags: apt, 18.04, gnome, lightdm

I am new to this forum and need help desperately to fix my Ubuntu desktop display. I know this question is already asked so many times and I already tried but no success so far.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and shut down my computer normal way but display manager stopped working when I turned on my computer in morning. First it was sticking in terminal at `Display Manager not working` then I tried to fix and reinstall lightdm , gnome shell and gdm3 but nothing worked.

Now system saying `Overlays : missing lower dir` and it goes to `tty1`. I can't install anything at all on my system and I am receiving message

```
"You don't have enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

I expected to have > 100GB free space and also used `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove` but nothing is working for me, and instead I only have 13.6 MB free.  Here's what `sudo parted -l` shows:

```
Reading package lists ... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information ... Done 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 106 not to upgrade. 
Model: ATA PNY CS900 240GB (scsi) Disk 
/dev/sda : 240GB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B 
Partition Table: msdos 
Disk Flags: 
Number Start  End  Size  Type    File system Flags 
    1 1049KB 240GB 240GB primary ext4        boot
```

Here is the output of  *df -x squashfs --total*

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used    Available   use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      229700940    218060280          0   100%   /
tmpfs            4024044            0    4024044     0%   /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120            4       5116     1%   /run/lock
tmpfs            4024044            0    4024044     0%   /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             804808            0     804808     0%   /run/user/1000
total          243365684    218061632   13663392    95%   -
```

Comment: Please check above output and let me know if it makes any sence. I can't copy and paste from original computer so I typed here myself. Thanks

Comment: Hi , ```df -i && du -h ``` terminal going into very fast infinite loop .

Comment: Its lots of content, please let me know exactly what information we need.

Comment: Hi @K7AAY , thank you for helping. Please let me know where and what sort of files can I delete? I have to delete files from terminal only.

Comment: Hi @K7AAY , big big thank you for helping. I deleted backups and logs files and freed more that 80% space , now disk used space is only 13%. I got my display ack and GUI is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: I can only see my question and below comments, can't see any answer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't 100 GB free space as you expected; only 13.6 GB. I'd suggest searching for extra backups which could be moved out of /dev/sda and log files which could be deleted, as illustrated in https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/5-ways-free-up-space-on-ubuntu .

`du -h` shows where files are concentrated and can help you see where the low-hanging fruit are, where large numbers of files are.